# Laravel 4: (routing?) to search keyword url

Tags: json, routes, laravel-4, keyword, q

Let's say for example in results q='sports', how would I be able to make it www.example.com/results?q=sports or whatever? And when I type manually in the url www.example.com/results?q=books it would search for books.

The response is in json btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to process the parameter from within whatever controller '/results' is routed to, eg:

```
if isset($_GET['q']) {
    $searchCategory = $_GET['q'];
}
```

Another option would be to have `q` as a function parameter on a controller method:

```
class MyController extends BaseController {
    public function __construct() {}

    public function getSearch($searchCategory) {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

And this would be accessible via:

```
http://www.example.com/search/books
```